# Why spoj is giving wrong answer for this solution of Euler Totient's Function?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I am solving [ETF](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/ETF/) problem of SPOJ. I am using sieve of eratosthenes method to compute primes and then using basic definition of Phi but SPOJ is giving wrong answer. I have tested it on GCC compiler with in the range of 0 to 1000,000 mentioned there. But couldn't find the error.
I know it's a bit painful to look into someone else's code but I really appreciate any help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PRIME_COUNT 2000

int main()
{
        long unsigned int number;
        long sieveArray[PRIME_COUNT],primes[PRIME_COUNT],prime_count=0;
        int i=2,j,test_cases;
        long phi, tempNumber;

        memset(sieveArray,0,PRIME_COUNT*sizeof(long));

        while(1)
        {
                if(i>PRIME_COUNT)
                        break;
                if(sieveArray[i]==0)
                {
                        primes[prime_count++]=i;
                        for(j=i;j<PRIME_COUNT;j=j+i)
                        {
                                sieveArray[j]=1; 
                        }
                }
                i++;
        }


        scanf("%d",&test_cases);

        for(i=0;i<test_cases;i++)
        {
                scanf("%ld",&number);

                if(number!=0)
                {
                        phi=number;
                        tempNumber=number;
                        for(j=0;primes[j]*primes[j]<=tempNumber;j++)
                        {
                                if(tempNumber%primes[j]==0)
                                {
                                        phi*=(primes[j]-1);
                                        phi/=primes[j];
                                        while(tempNumber%primes[j]==0)
                                                tempNumber=tempNumber/primes[j];
                                }
                        }
                        if(tempNumber!=1)
                        {
                                phi*=(tempNumber-1);
                                phi/=tempNumber;
                        }
                }
                else 
                        phi =number;

                printf("%ld\n",phi);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset(sieveArray,0,PRIME_COUNT*sizeof(long));` is poor style; write `memset(&sieveArray, 0, sizeof sieveArray);`, or even better, remove that entirely and use `long sieveArray[PRIME_COUNT] = { 0 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change your `long`s to `long long`s, or exchange the order of

```
                            phi*=(tempNumber-1);
                            phi/=tempNumber;
```

to

```
                            phi/=tempNumber;
                            phi*=(tempNumber-1);
```

(and all the other similar lines) to keep your temp values inside the bounds of the datatype. First delete, and only then, multiply. To see why, consider the case when `number` is a prime number just below your top limit.

Incidentally, your  `if(sieveArray[i]==0)` will try to access one-past-end element of your `sieveArray[PRIME_COUNT]` array, when `i==PRIME_COUNT`.